# How to make onKeyPress work with TextField in swift?

Tags: swift, events, swiftui, appkit

Implementing markdown text editor.

Each line of text is a `TextField`.

Need to switch line on  and

**First attempt:**

```swift
TextField(...)
 .onKeyPress(.downArrow) {
    print("down")
    return .handled
 }
```

This event is never fired

**Second attempt:**

```swift
import SwiftUI

class CustomTextField: NSTextField {
    override public var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { true }
    
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("key down with character: \(String(describing: event.characters)) " )
        super.keyDown(with: event)
    }
}

struct LineEditor: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }
    
    typealias NSViewType = CustomTextField
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustomTextField {
        let view = CustomTextField(string: text)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: CustomTextField, context: Context) {
        nsView.stringValue = text
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: LineEditor
        
        init(_ parent: LineEditor) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
            let field = obj.object as! NSTextField
            self.parent.text = field.stringValue
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

`keyDown` is never called either.

**Question**: how to track key press events properly in modern `SwiftUI`?

Comment: please share desire screenshot or video

Comment: I want to achieve the same effect as in text editors, when you can change lines using up and down arrows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiline texts you need to use `TextEditor`.

But in case you still need to use set of TextFields like this you need sth like the following code.

(Just copy-paste the code. All works with any count of pre-defined TextFields :)

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text1: String = "1234"
    @State var text2: String = "2345"
    @State var text3: String = "3456"
    @State var text4: String = "4567"
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text1)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f1)
            TextField("", text: $text2)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f2)
            TextField("", text: $text3)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f3)
            TextField("", text: $text4)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f4)
        }
        .onAppear { keyboardUpDownSubscribe() }
    }
}


extension ContentView {
    func keyboardUpDownSubscribe() {
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { (aEvent) -> NSEvent? in
            print(aEvent.keyCode)
            
            guard focusedField != nil else { return nil }

            guard aEvent.specialKey != nil else { return aEvent }
            
            switch aEvent.specialKey! {
            case .downArrow:
                focusNextField()
            case .upArrow:
                focusPreviousField()
            default:
                break
            }
            
            return aEvent
        }
    }
    
    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case f1, f2, f3, f4
    }
    
    private func focusPreviousField() {
        focusedField = focusedField.map {
            Field(rawValue: $0.rawValue - 1) ?? Field.allCases.first!
        }
    }
    
    private func focusNextField() {
        focusedField = focusedField.map {
            Field(rawValue: $0.rawValue + 1) ?? Field.allCases.last!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer, because it look like a more valid approach

Comment: But i don't like specifying keys by  numeric `keyCode`. Is there an enumeration for them in NSEvent?

Comment: Just create own enum or use existing enums from internet (there is a lot enums for this). I see no problem with this.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/swillits/df648e87016772c7f7e5dbed2b345066 or sth like this

Comment: There is `aEvent.specialKey` enum

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This is not an direct answer on the question but a way how to implement a editor in SwiftUI

You should better use **TextEditor** View. It implements the line switching automatically and is thought to be used as a Editor

Apple Developer Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor/

---

## Old answer

I think you try to use the new .onKeyPress function which is new in macOS 14 Beta in your first attempt. The documentation of this function says that your view (in the case of your first attempt the TextField) has to be in focus in order to get this function working correctly.
So in order that your code works properly you have to add something like this:

```
TextField(...)
    .focusable() // Not sure if needed
    .focused($infocus) // variable that indicates if the TextField or View is currently in focus
    .onKeyPress(keys: [.downArrow]) { arrowpress in 
        print("down")
        return .handled
    }
```

Also note that I have changed the function arguments and added

```
arrowpress in
```

where arrowpress in is a variable name that stores the exact key that is pressed if you use multiple keys as arguments to detect.
So you could use on .onKeyPress to detect .downArrow and .upArrow like this:

```
TextField(...)
    .focusable() // Not sure if needed
    .focused($isfocused) // variable that indicates if it is in focus
    .onKeyPress(keys: [.downArrow, .upArrow]) { arrowpress in
        if (arrowpress == .downArrow) {
            // Your Code executed when Arrow down is pressed
        }
        if (arrowpress == .upArrow) {
            // Your Code executed when Arrow up is pressed
        }
        return .handled
    }
```

Be sure to change the focus if needed and to declare the variable if the view is focused as a bool!

Note that this is still in Beta and the function may change over time
Note I forgot to add .characters to arrowpress
Note Looks like the code won't work like expected so I am sorry for this misleading answer

Comment: Hi @radioactiveray! Sadly, your code doesn't work.

Comment: Here's how I tested it: https://codefile.io/f/vNedOjqcVB

Comment: I forgot the .characters at arrowpress I used this tutorial to look how it worked [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-and-respond-to-key-press-events)

Comment: It still doesn't help. This tutorial uses `Text` component, which doesn't allow to input text. And `.characters` has `String` type

Comment: I personally cannot verify if it works so I am sorry for my misleading answer

Comment: After a while I think this new function won't work anyway because it could eventually conflict with the real text you write in the TextField but I also noticed that there is a SwiftUI View called TextEditor which may be better when you implement a markdown editor

Comment: The [`TextEditor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor) view is definitely worth taking a look at, although it doesn't answer the original question of "How to make onKeyPress work with TextField in swift?". I understand that this might be what @gavrilikhin.d actually is looking for though.

Comment: I have now updated my whole answer so it just shows the new one and added a disclaimer that it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Sadly, `TextEditor` isn't suitable for me, as each line should be rendered differently, depending on focus state. Focused line is plain text, while unfocused are rendered as markdown

Comment: @radioactiveray, please don't completely rewrite your answers, if they have comments. Comments start to make no sense

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best/only way, but what about adding a hidden button with a bound keyboard shortcut for each key you want to handle?

e.g.

```swift
TextField("", text: $text)
    .background {
        ZStack {
            Button("") {
                print("TODO: focus previous field")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut(.upArrow, modifiers: []))

            Button("") {
                print("TODO: focus next field")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut(.downArrow, modifiers: []))
        }
        .opacity(0)
    }
```

Note: The empty modifiers array (`modifiers: []`) is important as the shortcut will otherwise also require the command key.

#### Edit: Full example with Andrew's focus switching logic to prove that this works for more than 2 text fields

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text1: String = "1234"
    @State var text2: String = "2345"
    @State var text3: String = "3456"
    @State var text4: String = "4567"

    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case f1, f2, f3, f4
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text1)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f1)
            TextField("", text: $text2)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f2)
            TextField("", text: $text3)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f3)
            TextField("", text: $text4)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .f4)
        }
        .background {
            ZStack {
                Button("") {
                    focusedField = focusedField.map {
                        Field(rawValue: $0.rawValue - 1) ?? Field.allCases.first!
                    }
                }
                .keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut(.upArrow, modifiers: []))

                Button("") {
                    focusedField = focusedField.map {
                        Field(rawValue: $0.rawValue + 1) ?? Field.allCases.last!
                    }
                }
                .keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut(.downArrow, modifiers: []))
            }
            .opacity(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg, it works. Thanks! I will mark this as an answer, but will wait a little before assigning award as it looks more like hack.

Comment: Happy to hear! :) I use this "hack" myself in my own apps and it has worked quite well, although I have not used it in combination with a text field like this before.

Comment: Better to use `background { }` as `background()` is deprecated

Comment: Good callout! I edited my answer. :) (I'm not on the beta yet so I have not noticed this deprecation.)

Comment: It's better to wait till stable release. In current state XCode 15 broke our code :) A lot of bugs too. Hope they will fix it soon

Comment: this will work only in case of count of TextFields == 2. Bad solution because of author didn't tell that there will be only 2 lines.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA please don't say that a solution is bad before you test it. My solution has nothing to do with the amount of text fields. The hidden buttons are not bound to each text field, they are just acting as "global listeners" in the same way that you added a `keyboardUpDownSubscribe`.

I updated my answer to provide an example with your focus switching logic to prove that this works for more than 2 text fields. Please review your comment after testing it, thanks!

Comment: This code works with in my case perfectly with any number of lines.

Comment: Even of this - usage of `keyboardShortcut` is really heavy for UI. 10 keyboardShortcut on invisible buttons + window resize can generate more than 50% of cpu load of M1 processor: https://prnt.sc/22x1od3 ; 20 usages of `keyboardShortcut` can load M1 cpu up to 95% on window resize; So any solution that uses `keyboardShortcut` is bad in case of application for publishing, but not for own usage. So still - solution is bad.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA that's a valid point